# Copy float values from within lists of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, probability

I do apologize if I'm not looking in the right places, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get a value from say 
`list[[1,2,3][4,5,6.01]]` , `list[1][2]` integrated into code as anything but a list.

```
import random
fruits = [
['mango',7],
['apple',4],
['kiwi',6],
['grape',12],
['pear',3]
]
#Finding Probability
def setup():
    fsum = 0;
    prob = 0;
    i = 0
    #Finding the sum
    while i < len(fruits):
        fsum += fruits[i][1]
        i += 1
    i = 0
    #Calculating Probability
    while i < len(fruits):
        prob = [fruits[i][1] / fsum]
        fruits[i].append(prob)
        i += 1
    print(fsum)
    print(fruits)
setup()
def pick(x):
    rand = random.random()
    index = 0
    while rand > 0:
        #How do I get the value of the float in the list from the next line
        #(fruits[index][2])
        #to be stored in a variable that I can plug into this.
        #rand = rand - (var)
        index+=1

pick (fruits)

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
prob = [fruits[i][1] / fsum]
```

You are defining `prob` to be a list with one value, just eliminate the unnecessary list, e.g.:

```
prob = fruits[i][1] / fsum
```

Then `fruits[index][2]` will be the probability.

You should consider replacing your `while` loops with `for` loops, e.g.:

```
while i < len(fruits):
    fsum += fruits[i][1]
    i += 1
i = 0
```

Is equivalent to:

```
for fruit in fruits:
    fsum += fruit[1]
```

Which could be be accomplished with a generator expression:

```
fsum = sum(fruit[1] for fruit in fruits)
```

But if what you are looking to do is just pick the fruit based on the relative weights (`fruits[i][1]`) then there is an easier way to do this in Py3.6, without the `setup()`, e.g.:

```
def pick(fruits):
    items, weights = zip(*fruits)
    return random.choices(items, weights)[0]
```

Prior to Py3.6 you could do:

```
def pick(fruits):
    return random.choice([f for fruit in fruits for f in [fruit[0]]*fruit[1]])
```

Comment: Oh my lorde , you are a saint!

Answer (score 0):

Just access the first item of the list/array, using the index access and the index 0:

```
 var = fruits[index][2][0]
```

Comment: I don't know why this works but it does. Thank you so much!

Comment: Note: the `[0]` is unnecessary if you eliminate the list construction from `prob = [fruits[i][1] / fsum]`